# Hibernate/JBoss Database Connections get reset and continues to use closed connection

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jboss

We're using Hibernate 3 and JBoss 7.0.2 with our Java application, and connecting to an old Oracle 9 database. When the application first starts up it's able to connect to the database just fine. However, after about 15 minutes the connections start the reset and close, and JBoss continues to try to use the closed connections. These are the errors we're seeing:

08:37:31,591  WARN JDBCExceptionReporter:71 - SQL Error: 17002, SQLState: 08006
08:37:31,592 ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter:72 - IO Error: Connection reset

07:26:17,839  WARN JDBCExceptionReporter:71 - SQL Error: 17008, SQLState: 08003
07:26:17,839 ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter:72 - Closed Connection

Datasource config from the standalone.xml:

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:/oracleDBOld" pool-name="oracleDBOld" enabled="true" jta="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
                <connection-url>
                    jdbc:oracle:thin:@<host>:<port>:<SID>
                </connection-url>
                <connection-property name="oracle.jdbc.RetainV9LongBindBehavior">
                    true
                </connection-property>
                <driver>
                    oracle
                </driver>
                <pool>
                    <min-pool-size>
                        0
                    </min-pool-size>
                    <max-pool-size>
                        300
                    </max-pool-size>
                    <prefill>
                        false
                    </prefill>
                    <use-strict-min>
                        false
                    </use-strict-min>
                    <flush-strategy>
                        FailingConnectionOnly
                    </flush-strategy>
                </pool>
                <security>
                    <security-domain>
                        oracleDBOld-domain
                    </security-domain>
                </security>
                <validation>
                    <check-valid-connection-sql>
                        select 1 from dual
                    </check-valid-connection-sql>
                    <validate-on-match>
                        false
                    </validate-on-match>
                    <background-validation>
                        false
                    </background-validation>
                    <background-validation-millis>
                        0
                    </background-validation-millis>
                    <use-fast-fail>
                        false
                    </use-fast-fail>
                </validation>
                <timeout>
                    <blocking-timeout-millis>
                        5000
                    </blocking-timeout-millis>
                    <idle-timeout-minutes>
                        1
                    </idle-timeout-minutes>
                </timeout>
            </datasource>
```

The Hibernate configuration is done programmatically:

```
        config = new Configuration();

        config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.datasource", (isOldNodeOrDesktop ? "java:comp/env/jdbc/oracleDBOld" : "java:/oracleDBOld"));
        config.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", (isDesktop ? "true" : "false"));
        config.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect");
        config.setProperty("hibernate.query.substitutions", "true 1, false 0");
        config.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", "true");
        config.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", "true");
        config.setProperty("hibernate.cache.provider_class", "org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider");
        config.setProperty("hibernate.generate_statistics", "false");
        config.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries", "false");

        // Domain class mappings
        config.addClass(com.lmig.requestit.domain.ApplicationGroup.class);
        config.addClass(com.lmig.requestit.domain.EIPAGApplication.class);
        config.addClass(com.lmig.requestit.domain.EIPAGApplicationEmail.class);
        config.addClass(com.lmig.requestit.domain.EmergencyAccessApplication.class);
        config.addClass(com.lmig.requestit.domain.EmergencyAccessApprover.class);
        config.addClass(com.lmig.requestit.domain.EmergencyAccessLNWUser.class);
        config.addClass(com.lmig.requestit.domain.EmergencyAccessNode.class);
        config.addClass(com.lmig.requestit.domain.EmergencyAccessPlatform.class);
        config.addClass(com.lmig.requestit.domain.EmergencyAccessRole.class);
        config.addClass(com.lmig.requestit.domain.EmergencyAccessSBU.class);
        config.addClass(com.lmig.requestit.domain.EmergencyAccessSysgroup.class);
        config.addClass(com.lmig.requestit.domain.EmergencyAccessUser.class);
        config.addClass(com.lmig.requestit.domain.EmergencyAccessUserAccess.class);
        config.addClass(com.lmig.requestit.domain.WindowsNode.class);
        config.addClass(com.lmig.requestit.domain.UnixNode.class);

        // Mapping not aligned with any domain classes; contains SQL
                    // queries
        config.addResource("oldOracleDB_queries.hbm.xml");

        // Build SessionFactory
        RequestITHibernateOldDBUtils.setSessionFactory(config.buildSessionFactory());
```

I've read about C3P0 for connection pooling within Hibernate, but I don't see it being used currently. I can't seem to figure out what is resetting the connection. Our network guys were able to trace that it was coming from our server, but I don't know what would close the connection after 15 minutes, or why it would continue to use a closed connection. Any tips on where to look would be helpful.

Comment: Please run this query `select name, value from v$parameter where name = 'resource_limit'` to obtain a value of `RESOURCE_LIMIT` parameter. If this parameter is set to TRUE, then please log in as the user which is used to connect to the database from hibernate, then please run: `select * from user_RESOURCE_LIMITS where resource_name like '%TIME%';` to check if there are any limits set for the duration of the connection for this user.

Comment: IDLE_TIME and CONNECT_TIME were both set to UNLIMITED.